# Dovecot / Postfix lda(root): Error: net_connect_unix(/run/dovecot/stats-writer) failed: Permission denied

Tags: postfix, dovecot

Getting this error:

```
Dec 15 07:40:39 example.com postfix/local[116804]: E5DFC9CD1: to=<root@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0/0/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: lda(root): Error: net_connect_unix(/run/dovecot/stats-writer) failed: Permission denied )
```

```
# ls -ld /run/dovecot/stats-writer /run/dovecot /run
drwxr-xr-x 25 root  root  720 Dec 15 06:29 /run
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root  820 Dec 15 07:18 /run/dovecot
srw-rw----  1 vmail vmail   0 Dec 15 07:18 /run/dovecot/stats-writer
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
dovecot    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
    user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

doveconf reports:

```
service stats {
  chroot = 
  client_limit = 0
  drop_priv_before_exec = no
  executable = stats
  extra_groups = 
  group = 
  idle_kill = 4294967295 secs
  privileged_group = 
  process_limit = 1
  process_min_avail = 0
  protocol = 
  service_count = 0
  type = 
  unix_listener stats-reader {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0660
    user = vmail
  }
  unix_listener stats-writer {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0660
    user = vmail
  }
  user = $default_internal_user
  vsz_limit = 18446744073709551615 B
}
```

Debian 11.  Postfix/dovecot/postfixadmin stack.

Any suggestions?  Any troubleshooting steps I could take?

Comment: anything else in OS & security stack (SELinux / apparmor) logs?

Comment: Not using SE linux, not using apparmor.

Answer (score 1):

add the below configurations to the file `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` and reload the dovecot service.

```
service stats {
  unix_listener stats-reader {
    group = mail
    mode = 0666
  }
  unix_listener stats-writer {
    group = mail
    mode = 0666
  }
}
service anvil {
  unix_listener anvil {
    group = mail
    mode = 0666
  }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this config is missing from the default installation?